# How to control the height of spinners

Tags: android

I have added 4 spinners to a alert box. The problem is the height of first two spinners appears same and that of next two spinners is more than the height of first two spinners. I haven't given any padding or margin and if given i have given same values to all 4 spinners. Why is that the first two appear different than the bottom two ??. Plz help me out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/alertbackground"
>

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner_addrequest"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:textColor="#130101"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"

/>


<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner_addrequest1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:textColor="#130101"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
/>

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner_addrequest2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:textColor="#130101"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
>

</Spinner>

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner_addrequest3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:textColor="#130101"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
>

</Spinner>
```

[plz see the screenshot to understand my scenario better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSaTa.png)

Comment: add your layout code

Comment: show your code ...

Comment: i have inflated this xml file in alert box using layout inflator. I have also tried using table layout or relative layout for the same but the output remains the same. Also if u see the screenshot, the text appearing on top of the last 2 spinners has some indentation. i dnt know why this is happening

Comment: you are missing end " from this xml. Are you sure that this is compiled xml code ?

Comment: oo yes. while copying the code i think i have made a mistake. I have closed the linear layout in the end. its a compiled xml code and i have added the screenshot of the output after compilation